# How to solve following error:"ReferenceError: StorageManager is not defined" """?

Tags: prebid.js

While Delivery the ad using prebid headerbidding it shows "ReferenceError: StorageManager is not defined" """ error in prebid debug. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

`StorageManager` was used in some of the prebid 0.xx versions to store data in the browser `localStorage`. This is mainly used by SSP adaptors that you have in place.

You might want to try testing removing bidders until you find the offending one to pinpoint which one it is---Also looking at the current github repository, it looks like prebid 1.0 doesn't have this, so its possible this might be resolved by updating your prebid version/configuration